# Replace text with an anchor tag which can call a function on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an XML string which is displayed in a `span` in a `pre` tag:

```
    <pre className="xmlContainer">
        <span id="xml-span"></span>
    </pre>
```

The XML looks something like this:

```
<root>
    <child-to-replace>
    <child-to-replace/>
    ...
<root/>
```

With multiple (unknown) number of the `child-to-replace` tag.

I replace `<` and `>` to display the xml which is contained in a variable `xml`:

```
let element = document.getElementById('xml-span');
var displayXml = xml.replaceAll('<','&lt;').replaceAll('>','&gt;');
element.innerHTML = displayXml;
```

I also want to replace all instances of the opening tag of `child-to-replace` with an anchor tag which calls a function `updateParentScope`. I have tried to simply replace it:

```
function updateParentScope(scope)  {
    //updates scope for parent
}

useEffect(() => {
    let element = document.getElementById('xml-new');
    var displayXml = xml.replaceAll('<','&lt;').replaceAll('>','&gt;')
        .replaceAll('child-to-replace',
            '<a onclick="updateParentScope(\"sometext\")" >child-to-replace</a>')
    element.innerHTML = displayXml;)

    element.innerHTML = replaced;
}, [xml])
```

This gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: updateParentScope is not defined` when clicked.

Is there a way to solve this or is replacing the text the wrong approach?

Comment: `displayXml` is just a normal dom element you insert to the `span`, it's not controlled by react. `updateParentScope` is supposed to define on `window` object, that's the reason you get the error. What's the purpose of `updateParentScope`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to change the anchor tag to a button, then get the element from the DOM after render with a useEffect hook. When the element is retrieved, add an event listener.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const cond = document.getElementById(btnId) || false;
    if (cond && !hasEventListener){
        var btn = document.getElementById(btnId);
        btn.addEventListener('click', updateParentScope)
        setHasEventListener(true);
    }
    setHasEventListener(false);
})
```

The `cond` check is to make sure the element is rendered in the DOM.

I needed to add hasEventListener to state in order to not add the event listener multiple times:

```
const [hasEventListener, setHasEventListener] = useState(false);
```

This is not an ideal solution as the function called by the `click` event does not accept parameters.